# How to fix when angular 2 component take full width of the page?

Tags: css, angular

My angular 2 components are taking full width of the page.
When I limit the component width, its margin is stretched to full width.
So I cannot bring other components beside this. How can I limit the width of components?
I tried display: inline, but no use.Still the component takes full width allowing nothing to come beside this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Item }    from './../item';
import { ItemComponent }    from './ItemComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'Item-Set',
  directives: [ItemComponent],
  template: '<div class="singleItem" *ngFor="let eachItem of itemList"><Item></Item></div>'
})

export class ItemSet{
  itemList: Item[];
  constructor(){
    this.itemList=ItemList;
  }
}
```

In style sheet

```
.singleItem{
  width:300px;
}
```

Comment: How can we help without seeing the code?? .... Post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue.

Comment: Added code. I have just started using angular2. @LGSon

Comment: We need a _working code snippet_, something that render a result, best as a stack snippet but a fiddle will work too

Comment: What is `.singleItem{
  width:300px;
}` at the end of your code supposed to do? This needs to be in the `styles: [...]` property of the `@Component(...)` decorator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the CSS to set the width at the correct place. In your example would that be the `styles` parameter of `ItemSet` or `Item` like

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/E9ukiHJ4K9eOIqjAX3gY?p=preview)

Either on the `ItemComponent` with the `:host` selector (self):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Item',
  template: '<div>Item</div>',
  styles: [':host {display: block; border: solid 1px red; width: 300px;}']
})
export class ItemComponent{}
```

or the parent component with `.singleItem` as selector

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Item-Set',
  directives: [ItemComponent],
  styles: [`
    .singleItem{width:300px;}
    :host {display: block; border: solid 1px green;}`
  ]
  template: '<div class="singleItem" *ngFor="let eachItem of itemList"><Item></Item></div>'
})
export class ItemSet{
  itemList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
})
```